# Hive left semi join with where clause

Tags: mapreduce, hive, hiveql

I'm running this query in Hive 13, but it won't compile. (It's continuing to throw ClassCastExceptions saying it can't be converted to a query.)

The query is

```
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;

create table J as 
select c1, c2, c3, c4
from 
A
left semi join B on (A.c1 = B.c1)
where ((c2 not in ('string_literal_1', 'string_literal_2', 'string_literal_3')) and 
(c3 >= (cast('${hiveconf:start_time}' as bigint)-24*60*60)*1000));
```

Why won't this run?

Comment: can you show your parameter value '${hiveconf:start_time}'

Comment: You are trying to cast the string `'${hiveconf:start_time}'` to `BIGINT`.  Lose the quotes.